How to determine complexicity parameter in rpart output
I am testing rpart on the data. And I have the following output of cptable. CP is complexity parameter.
I have two queries.

Currently I am using k = which.min(cptable$xerror) to find out number of splits. Is this logic correct? Or any better way to find out the number of splits? If possible please explain it programmatically as well since I am not good at programming.

How can I find out the complexity parameter (CP)? Currently I keep CP as 0. But as you see the I get a big tree in the output. Is there any way we can find out the best CP and give it as parameter instead of keep 0 by default? It would be great if you can explain logically and programmatically as I run this tree on many parts (for every region in my data) hence I do not want to hardcode CP parameter in the code





CP
nsplit
rel error
xerror
xstd




0.3691817
0
1
1.0068652
0.2445614


0.1047932
1
0.6308182
0.6437088
0.1812461


0.0138612
2
0.5260250
0.5766522
0.1483616


0.0047814
3
0.5121638
0.5738629
0.1475701


0.0042239
4
0.5073823
0.5811986
0.1470528


0.0011218
5
0.5031584
0.5725189
0.1479602


0.0004863
6
0.5020365
0.5757189
0.1479229


0.0000269
7
0.5015501
0.5747054
0.1479258


0.0000180
8
0.5031584
0.5725189
0.1479602


0.0000049
9
0.5020365
0.5757189
0.1479229


0.0000000
10
0.5015501
0.5747054
0.1479258



